# Understanding default behavior of branching?

Tags: oracle, express

db 11gxe and apex 4.x

i created a master detail page , there are buttons on it by default , like (cancel,delete,apply changes) and two buttons for getting the next order and the previous one --there a master table for orders .

there are also branches created by default for the button getting the next order and the button getting the previous one (the branch is conditional ofcourse) -- the condition is when-button-clicked .

these branches are created automatically because the buttons are exist , and there are conditions which are "when-button-clicked" --just this condition .

-- what i do not understand is that there are other buttons like "delete , cancel , apply changes" , and there were no branches created for them like the other buttons which i mentioned above ,

although they also navigate like the other buttons , and the condition is when-button-clicked as well ?

why in the first situation there are branches created automatically , and in the last situation there are not ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if there is a final "Default" branch (i.e. one with no conditions and not attached to any button), it will be used if no other branch is applicable.

Secondly, there are multiple points where branches can happen, and it depends on how much processing should be done before the branch is done.

Typical branches are in the "After Processing" section, which means all applicable validations and processing are done before the branch.

A "Cancel" button, however, typically doesn't want to do any validations or processing, so the button may have its Action set to "Redirect to URL" - so no branch is needed.

Alternatively (although rarely, in my experience), a Branch may be added to the "After Submit" section, which would skip any subsequent validations and processing. Or, it might be created in the "Processing" section, which would allow validations to be done but subsequent processing to be skipped.